# Hive Query, any good ways to optimize these unions?

Tags: sql, hadoop, optimization, hive, hiveql

ALL, I'm new to HIVE and general query optimization.

I have 3 unions that are more or less the exact same query.  The only reason why these unions exist is because my source table does NOT have weekend or holiday dates, and I need to persist a few basic values from the preceding calendar day that exists in the source table for the holiday/weekend date that doesn't exist.  The Dateadd function is really the only differentiator of the 3 unions (1, 2, or 3 days)

Is there any way to combine these 3 queries into one, or perhaps just do this in a more performant way?

I'm a bit stuck but I've already got this down from a 45 minute overall process to 4 1/2 minutes.  Just not sure how to optimize these unions.   Please help :/

```
   UNION ALL 

--ADDING 1 DAYS TO FRIDAYS--
select * from
(
SELECT a.portfolio_name, cast(date_add(performance_end_date,1) as timestamp) as performance_end_date, cast(0.0000000 as string) as car_return, a.nav, a.nav_id
,row_number() over (partition by a.portfolio_code,a.performance_end_date order by a.nav_id desc) as row_no
FROM carsales a
where

a.portfolio_code IN ('1994',1998,2523)
and  a.year=2020 and a.month=09
and DAYOFWEEK(performance_end_date) = 6
) a
where row_no= 1

UNION ALL 

--ADDING 2 DAYS TO FRIDAYS--
select * from
(
SELECT a.portfolio_name, cast(date_add(performance_end_date,2) as timestamp) as performance_end_date, cast(0.0000000 as string) as car_return, a.nav, a.nav_id
,row_number() over (partition by a.portfolio_code,a.performance_end_date order by a.nav_id desc) as row_no
FROM carsales a
where

a.portfolio_code IN ('1994',1998,2523)
and  a.year=2020 and a.month=09
and DAYOFWEEK(performance_end_date) = 6
) a
where row_no= 1

UNION ALL 

--ADDING 3 DAYS To Holidays
select * from
(
SELECT a.portfolio_name, cast(date_add(performance_end_date,3) as timestamp) as performance_end_date, cast(0.0000000 as string) as car_return, a.nav, a.nav_id
,row_number() over (partition by a.portfolio_code,a.performance_end_date order by a.nav_id desc) as row_no
FROM carsales a
where

a.portfolio_code IN ('1994',1998,2523)
and  a.year=2020 and a.month=09
and performance_end_date in ('2020-09-04 00:00:00.000','2020-10-09 00:00:00.000')
) a
where row_no= 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's exactly like you wrote, that the only difference is the date_add parameter function, you could take the sql from one of the unions and cross join it with a union between 1,2 and 3 constastants. Maybe the cross join will work better than the union; depends also on the numbers from source. Also, you could filter the rownumber just before doing the Cross join, in order to join less rows. In the example posted below I didn't filtered the row number.

The query will look like this:

```
SELECT a.portfolio_name, 
       Cast(Date_add(a.performance_end_date, crs.crs) AS TIMESTAMP) AS 
       performance_end_date, 
       a.car_return, 
       a.nav, 
       a.nav_id, 
       a.performance_end_date, 
       a.row_no 
FROM   (SELECT a.portfolio_name, 
               -- Cast(Date_add(performance_end_date, 1) AS TIMESTAMP) AS performance_end_date, 
               Cast(0.0000000 AS STRING)   AS car_return, 
               a.nav, 
               a.nav_id, 
               a.performance_end_date, 
               Row_number() 
                 OVER ( 
                   partition BY a.portfolio_code, a.performance_end_date 
                   ORDER BY a.nav_id DESC) AS row_no 
        FROM   carsales a 
        WHERE  a.portfolio_code IN ( '1994', 1998, 2523 ) 
               AND a.year = 2020 
               AND a.month = 09 
               AND Dayofweek(performance_end_date) = 6) a 
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 crs 
                   UNION ALL 
                   SELECT 2 
                   UNION ALL 
                   SELECT 3) crs
```

EDIT 1: regarding the comments about date1 or date2, you could do exatly like you wrote. In the where clause, put  date_column = something or date_column = something.

```
SELECT a.portfolio_name, 
       Cast(Date_add(a.performance_end_date, crs.crs) AS TIMESTAMP) AS 
       performance_end_date, 
       a.car_return, 
       a.nav, 
       a.nav_id, 
       a.performance_end_date, 
       a.row_no 
FROM   (SELECT a.portfolio_name, 
               -- Cast(Date_add(performance_end_date, 1) AS TIMESTAMP) AS performance_end_date, 
               Cast(0.0000000 AS STRING)   AS car_return, 
               a.nav, 
               a.nav_id, 
               a.performance_end_date, 
               Row_number() 
                 OVER ( 
                   partition BY a.portfolio_code, a.performance_end_date 
                   ORDER BY a.nav_id DESC) AS row_no 
        FROM   carsales a 
        WHERE  a.portfolio_code IN ( '1994', 1998, 2523 ) 
               AND a.year = 2020 
               AND a.month = 09 
               AND (Dayofweek(performance_end_date) = 6 or performance_end_date in ('2020-09-04 00:00:00.000','2020-10-09 00:00:00.000'))
       ) a 
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 crs 
                   UNION ALL 
                   SELECT 2 
                   UNION ALL 
                   SELECT 3) crs
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @F.Lazarescu answer, you can rewrite CROSS JOIN subquery.

Instead of this:

```
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 crs 
                   UNION ALL 
                   SELECT 2 
                   UNION ALL 
                   SELECT 3) crs
```

Use `stack()` UDTF, it will perform faster:

```
CROSS JOIN (SELECT stack(3, 1,2,3) as crs) crs
```

Comment: To be more specific, for some holidays I may need to add in only one row, and it looks like the cross join And stack  will take every date and add 3 rows right ?  I’m wondering if there’s a way to do this same setup but have more flexibility on defining how many rows need to be added based on the date.

Comment: @Amateurhour35, look at my post, at EDIT 1. I integrated your desired condition.

Comment: Thank you, The one thing though where we may be disconnected. 

So this solution works for bringing in 3 rows for every friday , and every date I specify.  What it doesn't do is allow me to specify how many rows to bring in for some of the dates that may only require 1 or 2 dates if that makes sense. Using thanksgiving as the example, I only need to persist the day before thanksgiving for 1 day in the future (dateadd of 1 ) , not 3.

Comment: Something along these lines at least conditionaly :  CROSS JOIN (SELECT case when Dayofweek(a.performance_end_date) = 6 then stack(2, 1,2)
       when a.performance_end_date in ('2020-09-04 00:00:00.000') then stack(1, 3) end as crs) crs

Comment: @Amateurhour35 do you want to parametrize the number of rows generated?

Comment: Precisely, For dayofweek(performance_end_date) = 6 that's always going to be 2 rows, but there are holidays which can be 1, 2, or 3 rows depending upon where they fall in the week.  I don't mind hardcoding those, but would need a solution to account for them. That's really the primary reason I did that funky union to begin with.

Comment: @Amateurhour35 For example like this `set hivevar:num_rows=3;

select pos+1 as crs from (
select posexplode(split(space(${hivevar:num_rows}-1),' ')) as (pos, x)
)crs`

Comment: @You can calculate `hivevar:num_rows` parameter and pass it to the script

Comment: Very dumb question, but if my connection point is an ODBC driver and the results / query  are being generated in excel, can I still use parameters?  I'm going to test now to see if it works.

Comment: @Amateurhour35 then you probably can substitute parameters by some other means (excel or wba, etc) and pass already parametrized query to the ODBC. It's a wild guess

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222793/discussion-between-amateurhour35-and-leftjoin).